# Timer на php и Javascript (решено)

Tags: javascript, php

Существует код таймера, работает отлично, но всегда есть какое нибудь "Но". это "Но" заключается в том, что работает на одной и той же странице лишь один таймер, вместо нужного количества.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Код самого счетчика

```
<?php
// we will be sending Javascript codes, remember...
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');

// select the timezone for your countdown
$timezone = trim($_GET['timezone']);
putenv("TZ=$timezone");

// Counting down to New Year's on 2020
$countdown_to = trim($_GET['countto']); // 24-Hour Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

// Getting the current time
$count_from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // current time -- NO NEED TO CHANGE

// Date difference function. Will be using below
function datediff($interval, $datefrom, $dateto, $using_timestamps = false) {
  /*
    $interval can be:
    yyyy - Number of full years
    q - Number of full quarters
    m - Number of full months
    y - Difference between day numbers
      (eg 1st Jan 2004 is "1", the first day. 2nd Feb 2003 is "33". The datediff is "-32".)
    d - Number of full days
    w - Number of full weekdays
    ww - Number of full weeks
    h - Number of full hours
    n - Number of full minutes
    s - Number of full seconds (default)
  */

  if (!$using_timestamps) {
    $datefrom = strtotime($datefrom, 0);
    $dateto = strtotime($dateto, 0);
  }
  $difference = $dateto - $datefrom; // Difference in seconds

  switch($interval) {

    case 'yyyy': // Number of full years

      $years_difference = floor($difference / 31536000);
      if (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom), date("j", $datefrom), date("Y", $datefrom)+$years_difference) > $dateto) {
        $years_difference--;
      }
      if (mktime(date("H", $dateto), date("i", $dateto), date("s", $dateto), date("n", $dateto), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $dateto)-($years_difference+1)) > $datefrom) {
        $years_difference++;
      }
      $datediff = $years_difference;
      break;

    case "q": // Number of full quarters

      $quarters_difference = floor($difference / 8035200);
      while (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom)+($quarters_difference*3), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $datefrom)) < $dateto) {
        $months_difference++;
      }
      $quarters_difference--;
      $datediff = $quarters_difference;
      break;

    case "m": // Number of full months

      $months_difference = floor($difference / 2678400);
      while (mktime(date("H", $datefrom), date("i", $datefrom), date("s", $datefrom), date("n", $datefrom)+($months_difference), date("j", $dateto), date("Y", $datefrom)) < $dateto) {
        $months_difference++;
      }
      $months_difference--;
      $datediff = $months_difference;
      break;

    case 'y': // Difference between day numbers

      $datediff = date("z", $dateto) - date("z", $datefrom);
      break;

    case "d": // Number of full days

      $datediff = floor($difference / 86400);
      break;

    case "w": // Number of full weekdays

      $days_difference = floor($difference / 86400);
      $weeks_difference = floor($days_difference / 7); // Complete weeks
      $first_day = date("w", $datefrom);
      $days_remainder = floor($days_difference % 7);
      $odd_days = $first_day + $days_remainder; // Do we have a Saturday or Sunday in the remainder?
      if ($odd_days > 7) { // Sunday
        $days_remainder--;
      }
      if ($odd_days > 6) { // Saturday
        $days_remainder--;
      }
      $datediff = ($weeks_difference * 5) + $days_remainder;
      break;

    case "ww": // Number of full weeks

      $datediff = floor($difference / 604800);
      break;

    case "h": // Number of full hours

      $datediff = floor($difference / 3600);
      break;

    case "n": // Number of full minutes

      $datediff = floor($difference / 60);
      break;

    default: // Number of full seconds (default)

      $datediff = $difference;
      break;
  }

  return $datediff;
}

// getting Date difference in SECONDS
$diff = datediff("s", $count_from, $countdown_to);
?>

// Here’s where the Javascript starts
countdown = <?=$diff?>;

// Converting date difference from seconds to actual time
function convert_to_time(secs)
{
    secs = parseInt(secs);  
    hh = secs / 3600;   
    hh = parseInt(hh);  
    mmt = secs - (hh * 3600);   
    mm = mmt / 60;  
    mm = parseInt(mm);  
    ss = mmt - (mm * 60);

    if (hh > 23)    
    {   
       dd = hh / 24;    
       dd = parseInt(dd);   
       hh = hh - (dd * 24); 
    } else { dd = 0; }

    if (ss < 10) { ss = "0"+ss; }   
    if (mm < 10) { mm = "0"+mm; }   
    if (hh < 10) { hh = "0"+hh; }   
    if (dd == 0) { return (hh+":"+mm+":"+ss); } 
    else {  
        if (dd > 1) { return (dd+" дней "+hh+":"+mm+":"+ss); }
        else { return (dd+" день "+hh+":"+mm+":"+ss); }
    }   
}

// Our function that will do the actual countdown
function do_cd()
{
    if (countdown < 0)  
    {   
        <?php
            if(strtolower(trim($_GET['do'])) == 'r' )
            {
        ?>
        // redirect web page
        document.location.href = "<?=$_GET['data']?>";
        <?php } ?>

        <?php
            if(strtolower(trim($_GET['do'])) == 't' )
            {
        ?>
        // change text
        document.getElementById('cd').innerHTML = "<?=$_GET['data']?>";
        <?php } ?>

    }   
    else    
    {   
        document.getElementById('cd').innerHTML = convert_to_time(countdown);
        setTimeout('do_cd()', 1000);
    }   
    countdown = countdown - 1;  
}

document.write("<div id='cd'></div>\n");

do_cd();

<? exit(); ?>
```

Код страницы, на которой использован счетчик.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>До ЧАСА Х осталось...</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#cd {
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url(back.jpg);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center"> До ЧАСА X осталось  </h1>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="countdown.php?timezone=Europe/Moscow&countto=2015-01-01 12:00:00&do=r&data=http://onfireparadise.com"></SCRIPT>
<br>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="countdown.php?timezone=Europe/Moscow&countto=2015-02-01 1:12:00&do=r&data=http://onfireparadise.com"></SCRIPT> - ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ (ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ ТОЛЬКО КАРТИНКУ ФОНА)
<!--Тайм-зона http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
do=t&data= - текст, который будет написан вместо таймера по наступлению часа Х
do=r&data= Когда наступит час X, отправим посетителя на какую-нибудь страницу, например : http://ruseller.com
-->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Выложите только самые главные куски кода, в этом никто копаться не будет

Comment: из кода таймера вырезать будет сложно. 

<body> <h1 align="center"> До ЧАСА X осталось </h1> <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="countdown.php?timezone=Europe/Moscow&countto=2015-01-01 12:00:00&do=r&data=http://onfireparadise.com"></SCRIPT> <br> <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="countdown.php?timezone=Europe/Moscow&countto=2015-02-01 1:12:00&do=r&data=http://onfireparadise.com"></SCRIPT> - ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА НЕ РАБОТАЕТ (ПОКАЗЫВАЕТ ТОЛЬКО КАРТИНКУ ФОНА)

А нужно сделать так, чтобы было видно несколько таймеров.

Comment: Да, точно, мне тоже не особо интересно копаться в вашем исходном коде, выложите кусок, где по вашему мнению может быть ошибка.

Comment: Если бы я знал ошибку я бы не обращался, ведь так ? Я думаю ошибка где то в первом коде.

Comment: WTF все переменные глобальные?

"четкий код"

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему поиском в интернете. Оказывается нормальный таймер существовал в поиске. Немного переделал дизайн и сам код.

[Ссылка на таймер.](http://videouchilka.ru/timer.html)

Answer (score -1):

Давно занимался этой проблемой. Предлагаю интересный вариант поработай с библиотекой Jquery
 у нее есть готовые варианты тайменга. Скачай вот этот плагин "jquery.timers.js" ну и саму библиотеку конечно. Подойдет и старенькая "jquery-1.2.6.js"

А вот тебе и первые ласточки

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ru" xml:lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Построение пользовательских интерфейсов на основе библиотеки jQuery</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="Kotov A.V." />
<meta name="email" content="1vipperson1@rambler.ru" />
<meta name="domain" content="vkosmodrom.com" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timers.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    background-color:#E2F2E2;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
div {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
#example_1 {
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#00F;
  padding:0 15px;
}
#example_11 {
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#00F;
  padding:0 15px;
}
#example_2 {
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#0F0;
  padding:0 15px;
}
#example_3 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#666;
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:0 5px;
}
#example_4 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#666;
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:0 5px;
}
#example_5 {
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#666;
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:0 5px;
}
button {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:75px;
  height:22px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- css и javascript-коды специально размещены непосредственно на странице. -->

<div>Пример №2: <button id="start">Старт</button> <span id="example_2">0</span> <button id="stop">Стоп</button></div>
<div>Пример №3: <span id="example_3">Работает программатор</span></div>
<div>Отключение систем: <span id="example_4">Отключение A</span></div><div>Пример №1: прошло <span id="example_1">0</span> секунд.</div>
<div>Отключение систем: <span id="example_5">Отключение B</span></div><div>Пример №1: прошло <span id="example_11">0</span> секунд.</div>
<!-- вариант написания ф-ций setTimeout и setInterval на jQuery -->
<p align="center">Работа систем <div id='showTime' style="display: none; text-align: center;"><h3>Идёт самопроверка!</h3></div></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// пример №1 
    $("#example_1").everyTime(1000,function(i) {
        $(this).text(i);
    });
// пример №1 
    $("#example_11").everyTime(1000,function(i) {
        $(this).text(i);
    }); 
// пример №2
    $("#start").click(function() {
        $("#example_2").everyTime(1000, 'timer2', function(i) {
            $(this).text(i);
        }, 15);
    });
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        $("#example_2").stopTime('timer2');
    });
// пример №3    
    $("#example_3").oneTime("30s", function() {
        $(this).hide(2500);
    });

// пример №5    
    $("#example_4").oneTime("10s", function() {
    $(this).hide(3500);
    });
// пример №5    
    $("#example_5").oneTime("50s", function() {
    $(this).hide(2500);
    });

});

// пример №4 написания ф-ций setTimeout и setInterval на jQuery
$(function() {
$('#showTime').show();
var deltime = setInterval(function() {
$('#showTime').html('<h2>Отключите систему!</h2>').css({'color':'#cc0000'});
setTimeout(function() {
$('#showTime').css({'color':'orange'});
                       },1000);
                                     }, 3000); // setinterval javascript ( веремя через которое исчезнет текст 1)

             });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У меня таймер обратного отсчета, но за урок спасибо.